# $f(x)=e^{a+g(x)}$ can be written as $f(x)=e^a \left(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n e^{inx} \right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, exponential-function

Let $a\in \mathbb R, \{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subset \mathbb C$, suppose $g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n e^{inx}$ absolutely converges.

And let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C, f(x)=e^{a+g(x)}$.

Then, prove that $f(x)$ can be written as $f(x)=e^a \left(1+\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n e^{inx} \right)$.

---

Now, $f(x)=e^a e^{g(x)}$ so I want to show $e^{g(x)}=1+\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n e^{inx}$ for $\exists \{c_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset \mathbb R \ \mathrm{or}\ \mathbb C.$

This looks Taylor expansion,
\begin{align*}
e^{g(x)}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{g(x)^k}{k!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{
\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n e^{inx}\right)^k
}{k!}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{
\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n e^{inx}\right)^k
}{k!}\\
\end{align*}

Thus if I can show $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{
\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n e^{inx}\right)^k
}{k!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n e^{inx}$, this proof will finish, but I'm not sure this holds.

I wonder whether I'm on the right track.

I'd like you to give me any help.

Comment: you are almost done since the inside term $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (b_n e^{inx})^k$ is of the form you want with the justification of bringing terms together by absolute convergence

Comment: I still don't understand. What does "$(\sum b_n e^{inx})^k$ is of the form I want with the justification of bringing terms together" means ? @Conrad

Comment: if you raise a power series to power $k$ it means you multiply it with itself $k$ times so you get terms which are $k$ products of the original terms so $b_{n_1}..b_{n_k}e^{in_1x}...e^{in_kx}=c_{n_1,..n_k}e^{i(n_1+..n_k)x}=c_me^{imx}$ for the integer $m=n_1+..n_k$ and then you can group all the resulting terms on $m$; this requires interchanging terms in an infinite $k$-series which (like for the usual double series case) is justified by absolute convergence; and then of course you have the extra summing on $k$ which brings more grouping justified by absolute convergence

Answer (score 1):

There is a general fact that if $h(z)$ is an entire function then $h(f)$ admits an absolutely convergent series.

Denote
$$\|f\|=\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|,\qquad f=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ne^{inx}$$ For $f=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ne^{inx},\quad g=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_ne^{inx}$ we have
$$fg=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ne^{inx}\ \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_ne^{inx}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left (\sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k}\right )\ e^{inx}
$$ and
$$\|fg\|=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \left |\sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k}\right |\le \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \left (\sum_{k=0}^n |a_k|\,|b_{n-k}|\right )=\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|\ \sum_{n=0}^\infty |b_n|=\|f\|\,\|g\|$$

Let
$h(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty h_n z^n$ be an entire function. Then
$$h(f)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty h_n \,f^n,\qquad \|h(f\|\le \sum_{n=0}^\infty |h_n| \,\|f^n\|\le  \sum_{n=0}^\infty |h_n| \,\|f\|^n<\infty$$ as the radius of convergence of $h$ is infinite.